# VAR model residuals having significant correlation at lag 12

Tags: r, cross-validation, residuals, vector-autoregression

I have tried to fit a VAR model for two **stationary** time series `dlogsl_ts` and `dlogllc_ts`(tested by PP test and ADF test), the monthly river flow data. From:

```
VARselect(dlogdata, lag.max=10) # SC(3)
```

It seems that I could try fitting the model with a lag of 3. Overall my model seems good:

```
dlogllc_ts = dlogsl_ts.l1 + dlogllc_ts.l1 + dlogsl_ts.l2 + dlogllc_ts.l2 + dlogsl_ts.l3 + 
             dlogllc_ts.l3 

               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
dlogsl_ts.l1  -0.21404    0.06660  -3.214 0.001387 ** 
dlogllc_ts.l1  1.27827    0.05459  23.417  < 2e-16 ***
dlogsl_ts.l2   0.32462    0.09590   3.385 0.000762 ***
dlogllc_ts.l2 -0.61543    0.07962  -7.729 5.11e-14 ***
dlogsl_ts.l3  -0.19386    0.06617  -2.930 0.003529 ** 
dlogllc_ts.l3  0.20707    0.05516   3.754 0.000193 ***

Residual standard error: 0.3493 on 555 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-Squared: 0.7601, Adjusted R-squared: 0.7575 
F-statistic: 293.1 on 6 and 555 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16 

Covariance matrix of residuals:
           dlogsl_ts dlogllc_ts
dlogsl_ts    0.08150    0.06342
dlogllc_ts   0.06342    0.12197

Correlation matrix of residuals:
           dlogsl_ts dlogllc_ts
dlogsl_ts     1.0000     0.6361
dlogllc_ts    0.6361     1.0000
```

However when looking at the residuals it also seems that the model is not validated:

[image: Residuals]

My code:

```
fit_var1 <- VAR(dlogdata,type="none",p=3)
var1_residuals <- resid(fit_var1)
var1_residuals
acf(var1_residuals)
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
acf(var1_residuals[,1])
acf(var1_residuals[,2])
ccf(var1_residuals[,1],var1_residuals[,2])
```

Can someone please tell my why I am having this significant residual correlation at lag 12? It also happens with other models I have tried fitting. I have already tried to remove seasonality in the beginning:

```
dlogsl_ts  <- diff(log(sl_ts),  lag = 12)
dlogllc_ts <- diff(log(llc_ts), lag = 12)
```

If I simply use a VAR(12), the residual structure would not change much:
[image]

Now go with VAR(24):
[image]

And VAR(48):
[image]

Hardly changes the residual structure. It is of course useless to model such a high-order VAR, but just to demonstrate here the "stubbornity" of the residual correlation.

Comment: Although R code is central to this question, it seems to be a statistical question at heart.

Comment: Yes it is. The R code is just to show the things I've done with the data. But actually when fitting several models(distributed lag, var) I would always see a significant correlation in the residual at lag 12. Strange.

Comment: That comment was for future viewers who may have thought to vote to close because of the extensive code, not for you really. On a different note, your model was fit with `lag.max=10`. Do you think that may have something to do with it?

Comment: Thanks. After changing it to 12 I still get 3 from SC but when maximum lag gets greater, SC/AIC would give an order of 13. It's not of much use to have a model of such a high order.

Comment: Even if I do increase the order the correlation at lag 12 and 24 are still significant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this time series data, applying the difference operator of lag 12 is not enough to completely remove the seasonality pattern. That's why they are sparks in the residuals of the VAR model at lag 12, 24 and 36, etc.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have monthly data, and river flow is a very natural candidate to be seasonal. It evolves in 12-month cycles, thus creating serial correlation at lag 12. What you could do is either seasonally adjust the data before fitting the VAR model or include monthly dummies into the VAR model. You mention you have tried the former approach but it did not work, which is surprising; perhaps you could try an alternative seasonal adjustment procedure instead.

Second, the function `VARselect` considers only unrestricted models. By that I mean, if lag $k$ is included, lag $k-1$ will also be included; the function does not consider, for example, VAR(12) where all lag 1 through lag 11 coefficients are restricted to zero. Meanwhile, a relevant model for your data could perhaps be VAR(3) plus the 12th lag. That makes a VAR(12) model with a lot of empty lags (4 through 11). You could build the model manually and see how its AIC or BIC values compare to the ones found to be optimal by `VARselect`.

**Edit:** I checked out your data. It seems to me the problem is in asymmetry. Water levels have some positive spikes but not negative ones; the shocks are asymmetric. Using a simple VAR model does not account for that, which results in asymmetric and autocorrelated residuals (apparently the spikes are seasonal). Theoretically, perhaps a model with asymmetric errors could work; however, I doubt there is any relevant software implementation.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used a VAR(12) model with empty lags from 4 to 11 to fit the data and the AIC has decreased significantly. However the residuals structure do not seem to have changed much. I wonder why is that?

Comment: I also tried adding seasonal dummies in VAR() but not of much help.

Comment: That's strange. Including lag 12 should remove the serial correlation at lag 12.

Comment: If I keep increasing the order to 24 and 36 it would help remove the correlation at lag 12, and even higher order would help remove the correlation at 24 (with AIC decreasing). Do you have any idea why this occurs? Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "increasing the order to 24 and 36"? Do you include only the 12th, 24th and 36th lags extra to a full VAR(3) model? Could you also show the new model and its residual diagnostics by appending you original post? As mentioned before, it is quite strange (or actually very unusual) that you still have considerable autocorrelation at lag 12 (and perhaps 24, 36) in the residuals of a (restricted) VAR(12) model. Also, note that usual significance level of ACF/PACF does not apply to residuals from a VAR model; the significance you see there assumes raw data and is incorrect.

Comment: Hello Richard, thank you very much. I simply exploit my laptop by running a crazy VAR(24) model. I don't have enough "reputation" to edit the original post actually. What do you mean that "the significance you see there assumes raw data and is incorrect"? Are you saying the raw data is incorrect?

Comment: I mean the relevant 5% significance level is different for model residuals than it is for raw data. For example, Ljung-Box test applied on model residuals from an AR($p$) model takes in an argument of degrees of freedom used up when modelling the data (and that is $p$). The relevant null distribution becomes $\chi^2(T-p)$ (where $T$ is the sample size) instead of $\chi^2(T)$, or something similar. Ignoring the fact that you are testing model residuals rather than raw data will lead to incorrect null distribution, thus incorrect critical values and incorrect conclusions.

Comment: Also, it's unfortunate that you are not allowed to edit your own post...

Comment: Ah OK a very good explanation. Can you suggest other ways to test the VAR() model residuals/validate a VAR() model?

Comment: I have updated the post. Thanks again for all the help!

Comment: In the case of river flow, and hydrological and meteorological cycles generally, seasonal variations are typically rough rather than exact, as reflection on any familiar place's weather will bear out. But in this case, and many others, strong enough for discernible spikes.

Comment: I don't have more time right now, but it's good that you updated the post.

Comment: Thank you @NickCox. Should I try to live with these spikes then...

Comment: I can't see your data, but my prejudice is that environmental data with seasonality need either a seasonal component to the model or an explanation why not.

Answer (score 0):

Other than the plots I tried multivariate Ljung-Box test for the errors in the VAR(3) model, and it corresponds well with what's seen in the plot.

```
 Lags  Statistic df    pvalue
    4   6.363911  4 0.1735696
    6  16.121955 12 0.1857140
    8  23.377069 20 0.2706611
   10  35.631486 28 0.1522238
   12 297.827866 36 0.0000000
   14 305.924463 44 0.0000000
   16 311.151630 52 0.0000000
```

The first 11 lags can be considered as white noise however from the 12th things start to get messy.

Similar result also from a GARCH model **arma(1,1)+garch(1,0)**

```
 Ljung-Box Test     R    Q(10)  4.894078  0.8981404   
 Ljung-Box Test     R    Q(15)  142.1295  0           
 Ljung-Box Test     R    Q(20)  146.469   0           
 Ljung-Box Test     R^2  Q(10)  13.61885  0.1910976   
 Ljung-Box Test     R^2  Q(15)  76.52969  2.993006e-10
```

Would a multivariate SARIMA be a good choice at this point?

Thanks.

Comment: You will hardly find software for multivariate SARIMA. VAR with seasonal dummies or VAR on seasonally adjusted data could be among the viable alternatives.

Comment: Thanks Richard. My TA suggest me to stop here and say the model cannot be adequate anyway. Thanks again for all the help!

Comment: Could you post your data if it is not confidential? It would be interesting to see what caused all this trouble with the modelling.

Comment: Sure. I can't attach anything here so I put them in the blog: http://sss-blog.mozello.com/blog/params/post/635962/. I found the data on DataMarket.